# PowerShell Script to automate data entry to OpenOffice Calc Spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, openoffice.org, powershell-1.0, calc

I would like to be able to automate data entry to an Open Office spreadsheet using a PowerShell script, in the same way that Excel can be automated using PowerShell (see this [Scripting Guy](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept06/hey0908.mspx) example).  Is this possible?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954926/using-a-script-to-automate-data-entry-to-an-openoffice-calc-spreadsheet

Comment: Helen, No, the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954926/using-a-script-to-automate-data-entry-to-an-openoffice-calc-spreadsheet is based on any script; this one ios specific to PowerShell.  Given the lack of response to this question, I opened the second.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using the UNO CLI bindings. Unfortunately Powershell does not cope well with proxy objects, so you need to use reflection. For example,

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('cli_basetypes')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('cli_cppuhelper')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('cli_oootypes')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('cli_ure')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('cli_uretypes')
$localContext = [uno.util.Bootstrap]::bootstrap()
$multiComponentFactory = [unoidl.com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext].getMethod('getServiceManager').invoke($localContext, @())
$desktop = [unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory].getMethod('createInstanceWithContext').invoke($multiComponentFactory, @('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop', $localContext))
$calc = [unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader].getMethod('loadComponentFromURL').invoke($desktop, @('private:factory/scalc', '_blank', 0, $null))
$sheets = [unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument].getMethod('getSheets').invoke($calc, @())
$sheet = [unoidl.com.sun.star.container.XIndexAccess].getMethod('getByIndex').invoke($sheets, @(0))
$cell = [unoidl.com.sun.star.table.XCellRange].getMethod('getCellByPosition').invoke($sheet.Value, @(0,0))
[unoidl.com.sun.star.table.XCell].getMethod('setFormula').invoke($cell, @('A value in cell A1.'))
```

You could also try [AODL](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL) which should be much easier to use, but doesn't look like it's been updated recently.