# Using a script to automate data entry to an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet

Tags: automation, scripting, openoffice-calc

I would like to be able to automate creating spreadsheets and adding data to an [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) spreadsheet using a script (any scripting language is acceptable - PowerShell, Python, or even JavaScript).

Is there a suitable library or tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this white paper:
[Examples for Open Office Automation
with Scripting Languages](http://wi.wu-wien.ac.at/rgf/diplomarbeiten/BakkStuff/2005/200501_OOo-Augustin/200501_BSF-Examples_Augustin.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Curious, I just looked at [OOo UNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno) to answer another question and the link is going to be useful again...